# Graphical Interface Detection

Tags: opencv, intersection, shapes

I am building a program that can detect the area that a circle and a line shares (intersects). I have been using OpenCV. However, my understanding based on my research here and elsewhere, is that OpenCV does not provide an 'intersection' function. Instead you have to calculate the pixel coordinates of the shapes and compare to see if the two shapes occupy the same pixel.

I am examining other GPU-accelerated libraries right now and continuing my research into OpenCV. However, after spending a few days on this, I wanted to ask the community if there is a simple object intersection function I am unaware of?

I am currently using C++, if that is relevant.

Comment: I guess what you need is a computational geometry lib like `CGAL`, not a graphical lib.

Comment: I've been looking at that. I was hoping OpenCV would accomplish what I wanted ... but it sounds like it won't.

Comment: Well the intersection() function looks like it should accomplish what I want

Comment: Do you have any sample images we can look at? because if you can find the center of the circle and the equation of the line, you can use geometry to find the intersection points, the sector, etc

Comment: If it is a line and a circle, there is a mathematical formula to calculate the intersection (it will have 2 points of intersection), I do not understand why would you need to use GPU libraries for it... unless that you have to do a million of them...

Comment: I do have to do millions of them ;) I'm going to end up using cuda or a thread on several titans ... eventually .. but I have to design this thing first. I'm actually just going back to OpenCV for now and doing it mathematically, but, it's super slow